# VS2015: The type 'xxx' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly

I used to have fully working codes without any errors in VS2013.  But when I switched to VS2015, I got the same error in all my projects like the following screenshot.

[image]

And my codes for IMessageControl is as the following:

```
public interface IMessageControl
{
    void DisplayErrorMessage(string msg);
    void DisplayInfoMessage(string msg);
    void ClearMessage();
}
```

Even though it is showing as an error in VS2015, it is still running successfully in the website without any errors.  It's also happening in my colleague PC when he switched to VS2015.

Is there anyway to get rid of this error?  Did I miss a setting or VS2015 have different Debug Settings?